# Environment variable inside ecs container definition vs same environment variable defined in Dockerfile. Which one will be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

If there is an environment variable `SAMPLE_VALUE` defined in the ecs task definition like so

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "command": [
        "./app"
      ],
      "image": "sample-image:latest",
      "name": "sample-app",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "SAMPLE_VALUE",
          "value": "ABC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If the same environment variable `SAMPLE_VALUE` is defined again inside the Dockerfile of `sample-image` like so

```
...
...
ENTRYPOINT ["run.sh", "app"]
```

The content of `run.sh` is

```
#!/bin/sh

export SAMPLE_VALUE=XYZ
exec $1
```

What value would `app` get from the variable `SAMPLE_VALUE`? Would it be `XYZ` or `ABC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority here would be:

1. `ENV` declarations in the Dockerfile will be used by default.
2. Environment-variable settings when you launch the container, including the ECS setting you show (but also `docker run -e`, Compose `environment:`, Kubernetes `env:`) override the image's `ENV`.
3. Any environment variables the main container process sets itself will override both of these.

So in your example, the main container process is `run.sh`, and that ignores whatever was previously in the environment and sets `$SAMPLE_VALUE` itself; when it `exec` the actual command, it will see `SAMPLE_VALUE=xyz`.

You can illustrate this a little further by printing out the previous value:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "SAMPLE_VALUE was ${SAMPLE_VALUE}"
export SAMPLE_VALUE=xyz
exec "$@"
```

This will print out the `ABC` value set in the ECS definition, but then run the actual program with the value set to `xyz`.